# How can I do relationships in Microsoft Access (SQL Based DB)

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Suggest me the best way to do relationship in Microsoft Access,

For example: I have 10 user, each user has 10 products total 100 products, and each product has 10 orders total 1000 order,

How can I show each user only their products and each product only its orders?

I don't have any experience with MS Access

Answer (score 1):

How you structure this data will not only depend on the specific data you will be storing, but also on how you will be accessing it. You will need to keep in mind things like, how often you will be writing data into Firestore vs how often you will be reading it; will fields of one object (e.g. Order) be shown when showing other objects (User/Product), how will you query the data?

I suggest you check [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data), which compares pros and cons of different ways of structuring data and use cases in which they are recommended.